# How can I customize the text "Turn On Bluetooth to Allow ... to Connect to Accessories"

Tags: ios, bluetooth, uialertview

I am creating an iOS app that requires the CoreBluetooth library to listen for iBeacon packets and then behave in a certain way (no connections). Currently, if Bluetooth is not on when the app boots up, an alert box comes up that says "Turn On Bluetooth to Allow (my app) to Connect to Accessories". Since my app doesn't require any bluetooth connections to accessories,I feel that the alert box text isn't accurate in my case. I'd prefer it to say something like "(My app) requires that Bluetooth be enabled. Please enable it in Settings".

Is this handled in the xcode plist, or in the code under "CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff" with an Alert View? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

To inform the user about how you intend to use Bluetooth, include the `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` key in your `Info.plist` file.
You select it under the name: `Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral...`

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't seem to be working. You're referring to the MyApp-Info.plist file in the root of my xcode directory, correct?

According to this link https://forums.estimote.com/t/ios-bluetooth-custom-message/2941 It seems like NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription is used for a different purpose.